# mdadm raid1 showing removed disk

Tags: debian, raid, software-raid, mdadm, raid1

I have a dedicated server which consists of two hard drives with 5 partitions each.

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
sda       8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk  
├─sda1    8:1    0     1M  0 part  
├─sda2    8:2    0   488M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sda3    8:3    0   7.6G  0 part  
│ └─md0   9:0    0  15.3G  0 raid0 [SWAP]
├─sda4    8:4    0   977M  0 part  
└─sda5    8:5    0   1.8T  0 part  
sdb       8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk  
├─sdb1    8:17   0     1M  0 part  
├─sdb2    8:18   0   488M  0 part  
├─sdb3    8:19   0   7.6G  0 part  
│ └─md0   9:0    0  15.3G  0 raid0 [SWAP]
├─sdb4    8:20   0   977M  0 part  
│ └─md1   9:1    0 976.4M  0 raid1 /boot
└─sdb5    8:21   0   1.8T  0 part  
  └─md2   9:2    0   1.8T  0 raid1 /
```

After having troubles with the server not rebooting because a disk wasnt recognized and checking my raid config I noticed that /dev/md2 (which seems to contain the OS and all data) has a removed disk and is only showing /dev/sdb5 as active and a second disk as removed.

```
sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md2
/dev/md2:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Fri Jan  3 09:18:45 2020
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 1943880704 (1853.83 GiB 1990.53 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 1943880704 (1853.83 GiB 1990.53 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 1
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Sun Sep 17 09:11:34 2023
             State : active, degraded 
    Active Devices : 1
   Working Devices : 1
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : srv10135:2  (local to host srv10135)
              UUID : 2dcfef18:2714aa4a:7a708454:42eb8813
            Events : 219026

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       -       0        0        0      removed
       1       8       21        1      active sync   /dev/sdb5
```

Examining both partitions (/dev/sda5 and /dev/sdb5) I can see that both are belonging to the same RAID and are marked as active

```
sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sda5
/dev/sda5:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 2dcfef18:2714aa4a:7a708454:42eb8813
           Name : srv10135:2  (local to host srv10135)
  Creation Time : Fri Jan  3 09:18:45 2020
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 3887761408 sectors (1853.83 GiB 1990.53 GB)
     Array Size : 1943880704 KiB (1853.83 GiB 1990.53 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262056 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : active
    Device UUID : d2b34f96:e2f0a43b:d3e85f43:b8cf7ea4

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Sat Sep 16 11:19:49 2023
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : 27e920f0 - correct
         Events : 189131


   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdb5
/dev/sdb5:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 2dcfef18:2714aa4a:7a708454:42eb8813
           Name : srv10135:2  (local to host srv10135)
  Creation Time : Fri Jan  3 09:18:45 2020
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 3887761408 sectors (1853.83 GiB 1990.53 GB)
     Array Size : 1943880704 KiB (1853.83 GiB 1990.53 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262056 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : active
    Device UUID : 78918ed5:59a78605:df84fcf7:91ba926b

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Sun Sep 17 09:16:06 2023
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : acbce60c - correct
         Events : 219236


   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : .A ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

Now im wondering if `mdadm --detail /dev/md2` is showing a wrong info on the RAID members or if /dev/sda5 is really missing in the RAID and if it is safe to just add it back into the RAID

Answer (score 1):

In general, `/proc/mdstat` shows the true, current RAID status.

`sda5` is really missing from the RAID array: notice how its event count is much lower than `sdb5`. Also notice how `sdb5` see an array status of `.A` - ie: with the first disk showing as missing.

You need to re-add `sda5` to the array issuing something similar to `mdadm /dev/md2 -a /dev/sda5` (triple-check this command *before* issuing it, though).

Comment: Also *superblock update time* is available and it differs by much. As the array has the write-intent bitmap, the resync should only cover the data changed since one drive fell off.